# Function to reverse every sub-array group of size k in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, sorting

I did this code so I reverse sub array group of integers but actually it only reverse the first sub array only and I don't know why this is happening!!!
Here is the code:

```
def reverseInGroups(self, arr, N, K):
    rev=list()
    count=0
    reach=K
    limit=0
    while limit<N-1:
        rev[limit:reach]=reversed(arr[limit:reach])
        limit=limit+K
        reach=reach+K
        
        if reach==N-1 or reach<N-1:
            continue
           
        elif reach>N-1:
            reach=N-1
            
                
    return rev
```

This is the the input,excpected output and my output:

```
For Input: 
5 3
1 2 3 4 5
Your Output: 
1 2 3 4 5 
Expected Output: 
3 2 1 5 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code online and its fine, but you have one logic error in your function to get your desired output.

```
while limit<N-1:
rev[limit:reach]=reversed(arr[limit:reach])
limit=limit+K  #3
reach=reach+K  #6
if reach==N-1 or reach<N-1:
    continue
elif reach>N-1:
    reach=N  #5
```

this is an image to see what I mean [image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8qgl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create new list `rev`, you can reverse items in list `arr`. For example:

```py
def reverseInGroups(arr, N, K):
    limit = 0
    while limit < N:
        arr[limit : limit + K] = reversed(arr[limit : limit + K])
        limit += K
    return arr


l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(reverseInGroups(l, 5, 3))
```

Prints:

```
[3, 2, 1, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this simpler solution:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = 5
k = 3
new_arr = list()
for index in range(0, n - 1, k):
    new_arr[index:index+k] = arr[index:index+k][::-1]
print(new_arr)
```

And the output is:

```
[3, 2, 1, 5, 4]
```

After putting this code in your function, it is as below:

```
def reverseInGroups(self, arr, n, k):
    new_arr = list()
    for index in range(0, n - 1, k):
         new_arr[index:index+k] = arr[index:index+k][::-1]       
    return new_arr
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do the loop in the increment of K and then reverse the array of that specific size

```
def reverseInGroups(self, arr, N, K):
    # code here
    for i in range(0, N -1 , K):
         arr[i:i +K] = arr[i:i +K][::-1]
```